# Retrieve data of all user id from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm try to populate listview with all messages of all users of my Android app, but, I got it populate listview with only one user messages because I'm inserting messages information in database this form:
Usuario > UID > Mensagem > Key creating with push > Data of mensagem.
For better verification follows image of the database on firebase.
[image: Structure of database firebase]

Can help me, please?
Hugs.

Comment: Getting **ALL** the data from the database is a bad practice.

Comment: Yes, but I used a condition to retrieve, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
database.child("usuario").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: snapshot.child("mensagem").getChildren()) {
                 listView.add(messageSnapshot.child("textoMensagem").getValue().toString());
             }
         }
    }

    ...
```

As you can see I add a `ValueEventListener` to retrieve **all children nodes** of "usuario" and then loop through its children to get to your messages.

*Tip: Think about (at least) posting your code/database structure etc. in English, it could make reading your question a lot easier.*