# Retrieve data from all users then show their user ID in a html table and update via button

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to have a table like this

[image: Desired table]

which will get data from the firebase database, here is my firebase database structure for requests [image: firebase request structure].

Here's my code which I tried to edit from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651782/retrieve-data-of-all-user-id-from-firebase), but as you can see from the table above the data says undefined.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="ex-table">
<thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
    <th>ID Number</th>
    <th>Request Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="tr">
    <td id="status"></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>


<script>

    var database = firebase.database().ref().child('Request');
    database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
    var content = '';
    snapshot.forEach(function(data){
          var status= data.val().status;
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<td>' + status + '</td>';//column2
        content += '</tr>';
    });

    $('#ex-table').append(content);
    }
});

</script>
```

This is for my admin panel which approves the requests of the users, also how can I do the approval using 2 buttons named Approve and Deny?

Sorry for the inconvenience I am new to firebase.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a keyword named `status` inside my firebase database. I replaced it and then boom it worked like a charm. I am very sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: check your answer as accepted, otherwise it will continue to show up.