# Retrieve data under user id from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data under all userIds. I tried what is suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651782/retrieve-data-of-all-user-id-from-firebase) see my code bellow:

```
final DatabaseReference ratingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer");

        ratingRef.child(RandomID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : ds.child("rating").getChildren()) {

                            if (ds != null){
                                Toast.makeText(RibsAndPowerboats.this, "It is: "+ds.child("rating").getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                }
```

But with this way it shows `NaN` and not the number that should have been shown. My Firebase Database is below:

```
"Customer" : {
    "Xqve54QUwwPo3NyZhcs2z4wkETB2" : {
      "3086181c-c391-4bab-a022-0a0e0bb2624c" : {
        "rating" : 4.5,
        "review" : "γγυηωυηη"
      },
      "Name" : "Ntinakos",
      "Password" : "123456789"
    },
    "mW5TtA3GxjNaaj3lAFcAFF3moQ22" : {
      "Name" : "Αχιλλέας",
      "Password" : "Achisyg_15"
    }
  }
```

So, is there another way to retrieve data under all userIds?

Comment: What do you mean by "data under all userIds"? Can you please indicate the exact data you want to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo I just need to retrieve "rating" value from every customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the rating value that exists under each customer, you need to loop through the DataSnapshot object twice. So please try the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference customerRef = rootRef.child("Customer");
customerRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Double rating = ds.child("rating").getValue(Double.class);
                            if (rating != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "rating: " + rating);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
rating: 4.5
```

Comment: Now it shows `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference` error

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry, my bad. Please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Now it is working perfect. Thank you very much!